# Create pop menu Sims's style when click on Character in Unity3D

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, character, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to build a game that uses a concept from the known game "The Sims". Right now I'm building the AI for a 3d Character, and I need the player to be able to tell where the character should go or do. I want to know the best ways to create a pop up menu with animations, kind of to show some choices, so that when the player clicks over the 3d Character he can pick wherever he wants to do. I know this must be using UI elements under a Canvas that's placed over the player. However I can not have 2 Canvas in a Scene and I don't know how to fix them to the character so that it moves with him. Thanks in advance.[image: Here you can see what I mean, this is the Sims Game]
Here you can see what I mean, this is the Sims Game

Answer (score 1):

You have two main approaches here:

1) Use a world space UI.

2) Use a screen space UI and position it in real time using a worldspace to screen space transformation.

Both of these topics will expand substantially when you approach them, so it's not possible to give any more specifics from here.

Having played the Sims a bit before though, I would suggest you use a world space UI system if you're chasing the same style as them.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many canvases as you want. To control levels of canvases (which one is on top) you use "Order in Layer" parameter in "Canvas" component of your chosen Canvas. The lower the number is the higher interactivity and visibility your canvas has.

You can create one canvas ant parent it to you character. AS the canvas will be smaller your should play with these parameters to get the resolution you want (don't over do it):

[image]

To make canvas always facing the camera you should give Canvas a new script, with a command:

```
canvas.transform.LookAt(camera.transform);
```

To control canvas' visibility you may use this code line:

```
canvas.enabled = bool;
```

Where bool is false when you want to hide it and bool is true when you want to show it.

In the "Sims" the visibility comes with animation which you may do also, but I would leave it after I did all the functionality.